# firebug showing wierd characters

Tags: firefox, firebug

For some reason my Firebug HTML tab keeps showing these weird characters such as: →‌¶‌→‌¶‌→‌ Can someone possibly show me how to get rid of this? Thx in advance! Here's a screenshot:

http://screencast.com/t/xWa9JAyKxY

![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0):

Just disable "show Whitespace" as below:
[image: "show Whitespace" option]